# Council Manager Govt

Tags: government

New here--thank you for taking a look at this question.

Can the council-manager form of govt operate efficiently and democratically at the national and state level?

I have researched online and can only find this form of govt at the local (municipality and county) level.  I do not know if it's just a terrible idea at the higher levels of govt or if entrenched political powers block even the discussion of.

For those that don't know, the council manager form of govt consists of an elected council responsible for legislative functions such as establishing policy, passing local ordinances, voting appropriations, and developing an overall vision, similar to a corporate board of directors. The council appoints a professional manager outside of politics and neutral to oversee the administrative operations, implement its policies, and advise it. The manager position is similar to that of corporate chief executive officer (CEO), except not being employed by the govt beforehand (outsider), providing professional management to the board of directors.

Political parties would still be free to operate and open (Council).  The national manager and those belonging to the International Professional Managers Association would have to be politically neutral in public.

Since the apolitical (politically neutral) national manager would be the head of govt, coalitions and govts would not need to form.  The council would have party leaders, but agreements between parties would shift based on the issue being discussed.

The story will be a modern otherworld story (not necessarily scifi as it's not focused on technology).  Maybe modern isekai?

I apologise for the length, but I was just trying to be as detailed as possible.  I appreciate any answers you could provide.  Thank you.

Comment: What would you get if you eliminate the emperor from the [meritocracy of the Imperial China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meritocracy#Imperial_China)? (I don't know, maybe elect Confucius as the head of the council. He doesn't need to take the decisions, just to make sure that the decision process is fair and logical)

Comment: Countries with an ordinary parliamentary system sometimes adopt this system in certain unusual situations; it is usually called a [technocratic government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technocratic_government_(Italy)). Famously, it was the solution adopted by Italy from November 2011 to April 2013 (the [Monti Cabinet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monti_Cabinet)). My own country, Romania, also resorted to such a system from October 2011 to November 2012 (the [Stolojan Cabinet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolojan_Cabinet)).

Comment: Who determines that the allegedly apolitical manager *actually is* apolitical?

Comment: ... The main problem with technocratic governments and why they usually are set up for limited periods of time is that a technocratic governemt can only administer the country as is, and cannot normally drive any changes, because they obviously lacks any democratic mandate.

Comment: Better suited for politics SE? (Doesn

Comment: @AlexP https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Cybersyn would have been an interesting combination between political and technocracy

Comment: The closer that you'll find in today's reality is [Switzerland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politics_of_Switzerland), but is still a bit far from your proposition. "The Federal Assembly convenes to elect the members of the Federal Council" - "The Swiss executive is one of the most stable governments worldwide. Since 1848, it has never been renewed entirely at the same time, providing a long-term continuity. " - but the executive is still political. The semi-direct democracy, in which laws can be challenged by the citizens in a referendum, keeps the politics in the executive  quite tamed.

Comment: @Cadence

In the real world, the ICMA handles this.  They can de-certify a city manager who fails to follow their regulations, making it easier for the city council to fire him, even if under a long contract.  Thank you for asking.

Comment: @AlexP

Could the parliament, through a party bill or private member bill, bring legislation, letting the govt just do administrative work and the parliament doing the lawmaking?  Would the majority still be spoken for as the parliament itself is not politically neutral technocrats?  Did the technocratic govt perform better in your opinion?  Did it provide a better national unity?  Thank you

Comment: Taking the decision of the executive's fitness or unfitness out of the hands of the electorate and vesting it in a private review board may be efficient, but it doesn't sound all that democratic to me.

Comment: Normally, most countries actually **do** have an apolitical (or at least, mostly apolitical) [civil service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_service), which does the day-to-day administration. The members of the civil service are very much more numerous than the members of the government. In the UK they are called civil servants, in France they are called fonctionnaires (with similar words in many Romance languages), it Germany they are called Beamter. A country can work for quite some time without a government; for example, Belgium famously went 589 days without a government (2010-2011).

Comment: @AlexP Makes one wonder if govt (executive) really is needed :) if the civil servants can hold their own for over a year without some political executive directing them.  Parliament could do that through committees and then the head of civil service could be the national manager (no change in role).  Hmm....  thank you.

Comment: *"Head of civil service":* there is no such thing, anywhere that I know of. There is a head of the civil service *per department*; for example, in the United Kingdom that role is called a [permanent under-secretary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent_secretary).

Comment: @AlexP They do exist, even in the UK.  Simon Case CVO (born 27 December 1978) is a British civil servant who currently serves as Cabinet Secretary and Head of the Home Civil Service since 9 September 2020, succeeding Sir Mark Sedwill.

Answer (score 2):

**For a while**

Efficiently and democratically? There's no reason why it should be less effective than choosing one of The Thing (the legislative assembly, names vary depending on where you are) as the titular head. The difficulty is in making that choice, since The Thing is formed of people who are interested, involved, and presumably competent. It's therefore going to be difficult to persuade them to pick an outsider as a leader - why isn't the outsider elected as a standard representative?

(If you want to force this situation, declare that one has to be a citizen to be part of The Thing, then say that your leader is extremely popular but a technically a foreigner in law. There's [precedent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler), although your leader will have a personality of your choosing.)

---

How the position might remain neutral is more difficult to answer - presumably it will draw people who seek influence (and therefore power/wealth). The leader's service might be rewarded handsomely (causing greed), moderately (causing bribery), or not at all (attracting only fanatics). In any case, transparency is your friend.

---

See also [*Yes, Minister*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_Minister) for some ideas on how the non-political parts of government can potentially influence the process.

Comment: I loved that show (yes, minister).

Answer (score 0):

In theory yes, in reality probably not, you're up against it when it comes to representational dilution. The governing body in a council manager government is quite small, and generally pretty efficient (for good or ill) and works well when representing a small electorate population. When you expand the electorate you either: 1. have to bolster the size of the government which hampers efficiency and tends to cause institutional inertia. 2. reduce proportional representation so smaller groups have less and less of a say and the larger and/or louder, political bodies begin to dominate policy. IF one could reconcile these issues then maybe but there are probably other issues that emerge at larger scales that aren't so obvious that will need to be overcome as well.

Comment: "When you expand the electorate you either:" It doesn't happen with public stock companies and the general assemblies. A small investor can still engage in [shareholder activism](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/shareholderactivist.asp) with a small stock and a big  mouth; true, that's not a democracy (one person, one vote) but it's still an exercise in representation and I see no reason for which the equality of representation cannot be written down in the "nation's charter"...

Comment: Mind you, I'm not saying that conducting the governance of a nation as proposed is possible, I'm just objecting to your dichotomy of "either paralysis or dilution of representation".

Answer (score 0):

The council manager form of government was part of the concept behind the US having a Congress (council) and a President (manager). There have been presidents who acted as if Congress was the ultimate authority that he had to report to. More recently, we have had a number of Presidents who wanted to be kings and rule over Congress.

This is one danger of a professional manager - that they use the position to become political figures in their own right and take over. What made it possible for someone to attempt to be king? Mass communications. Earlier than the 1860's, there was no way to have one person communicate with the whole country. Lincoln started some of that with how his speeches got transmitted via telegraph and printed widely. But the process really accelerated with national newspaper chains where one person could decide what the nation read. Then, radio and TV came along.

Having a professional manager brings another danger: that the elected officials over him/her rarely understand what they do and thus, can't determine if the manager is really following their wishes or is being corrupted or has his/her own agenda and is following that. So, what happens in many cases is that newly elected council members receive intensive training by the professional staff on what they are doing (and why what they are doing is the right thing to do - forget about what you were elected to change). Or the elected officials learn that their major donors are not being treated with special care by the professionals or have rejected the donor's wishes and the elected officials fire the competent professionals in order to hire someone who will allow the "proper" corruption to occur. Having professionals run things often mean a government that doesn't change direction quickly with changes to the political leadership.

Comment: Based on the dangers you mentioned, why is the council manager allowed at the local level even?  Why not just go mini-parliamentary, like many British cities (eg council leader being the equivalent of the city prime minister)?

Comment: Possibly it's easier to communicate with a local area and a small council.

Comment: @리주민  Why go with council manager at the local level? Because most managers are good professionals. The dangers get amplified the more power the position has. Even at the local level, there are plenty of examples of corruption, power, and doing wrong. But they are a small minority of managers. When a position has more power, that power attracts the wrong kind of people. At national level, it is best to have many checks and balances on the power that any one person or small group of people can have - because there are too many evil people wanting that power.